# PHP script to Generate Javascript & Highlighting in Zend Studio

Tags: php, javascript, syntax-highlighting, zend-studio

I have a PHP script that I am using to generate some rather complicated javascript for a web application. It is necessary that this script be generated by PHP for scalability reasons.

Here is my problem:

1. if I name the file `myscript.js`, then I have to use htaccess to tell the webserver to pipe this through PHP (not preferrable)
2. if I name the file `myscript.php`, then Zend Studio will highlight all the code as HTML instead of javascript.

What I am doing now is simply naming the script `myscript.php`, and wrapping all the code in `<script>` tags, then doing `include('myscript.php')` instead of the preferred: `<script src='myscript.php'>`.

I could thwart this whole problem if only I could tell Zend Studio to highlight this file as though it were a `*.js` file. Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Currently I am using versions 5.5 (for Windows, at work) and 6.1 (for Linux, at home).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there not a way to open your file with the Javascript editor ?

Something like right click on the file's name, then "Open With > Javascript editor" ?

Well, I've just tried with Zend Studio *(I don't find the version number, but it's a pretty recent one, downloaded less than one month ago -- and Eclipse based)*

To see "Javascript editor" in the "Open with" list, you might have to add a file association between .php and "Javascript". To do that, follow these steps :

- Windows > preferences
- general > editors > file associations
- add *.php to the list ("add" button) if it's not already in it (it is not by default, it seems)
- when you click on *.php, you see two entries in the list at the bottom :

  - php editor
  - text editor
- add "javascript editor" to this list (the other "add" button, next to the list) -- don't set it as default (as you only want a couple of .php files opened with it, not all of them)
- click OK to validate

Now, in the files list, you should be able to right click on a PHP file, and "open with > javascript editor"

And your file should be highlighted like a JS one, and not as PHP.

I'm not sure Zend studio will remember the fact that one file has to be opened with JS editor, though : you might always have to use "open with" for the file you are interested in.

Hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a very easy hack to cause zend to think of the PHP file as javascript:

```
// <script type="text/javascript">

alert("Hi");

// </script>
```

But I think Pascal's approach is cleaner...